# Запрос на обновление данных в таблице SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Мне нужно прибавить час к времени перерыва если время начала перерыва начинается до 10 часов, но при попытке выполнить код вылезает ошибка.

```
Update dbo.Таблица_из_запроса2
Set Время_окончания_перерыва += '01:00:00'
Where Время_начала_перерыва < '10:00:00'
```

Сообщение 402, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1
Типы данных time и varchar в операторе add несовместимы.

База данных: Почтовые отделения

[image: Проект таблицы]

[image: Её данные]

Comment: Set Время_окончания_перерыва += '01:00:00'  замените на `Set Время_окончания_перерыва = DATEADD(Время_окончания_перерыва, DATEDIFF(Время_окончания_перерыва, 0, GETDATE()), '01:00:00')`

Comment: Вылезла та же ошибка :c

Comment: `Set Время_окончания_перерыва = DATEADD(Время_окончания_перерыва, DATEDIFF(Время_окончания_перерыва, 0, GETDATE()), '01:00:00')`

Comment: не успел обновить,попробуйте новый вариант

Comment: Теперь вот так :c 
Время_окончания_перерыва не является известным параметром datediff

Comment: Приведите ваш полный пример с настоящими именами полей и укажите имя базы данных .

Comment: И какие данные в нем хранятся , date или time , аможет оба вместе datetime

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Готово

Comment: Я  Рад за вас ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.Таблица_из_запроса2
   SET Время_окончания_перерыва = DATEADD(hour, 1, Время_окончания_перерыва)
 WHERE Время_начала_перерыва < CAST('10:00:00' AS time)
```